# Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, вконтакте, бот

Пытаюсь создать бота для VK, но на строчки 5, 6 и 8 возвращает ответы Trying to get property of non-object in и Undefined property: stdClass::$object in.

```
require_once('config.php');
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 
$user_id = $data->object->user_id;
$message = $data->object->body;
$user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($conf['apiurl']."users.get? 
user_ids=".$user_id."&v=".$conf['v'].'&access_token='.$conf['standalone'])); 
$user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;
$temp_link = file($conf['temp_link']);
if($temp_link[0] != $album_link){
    file_put_contents($conf['temp_link'],$album_link);
    file_get_contents('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$conf['path'].'/create_photos.php');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($data);` сюда пожалуйста скиньте что вернёт эта функция. Вероятно api помимо всего возвращает ещё и массивы а вы пытаетесь использовать их как объекты.

Comment: object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(12) "confirmation"
  ["group_id"]=>
  int(159978906)
}